# Refractive index of air for different wavelangthes

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, refraction, atmospheric-science

When I tried to search about the refractive index of air, I found 1.00029. This is for which wavelength? How can I find refractive index of it for different wavelengthes like red light's wavelength ot purple's?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refractive_indices from this you can see , 589 nm light is the standard for measuring refractive index as we know it , also their change is directly proportional with frequency

Comment: Thank you. And another question. 589 nm is the wavelength after switching the environment or before it?

Comment: For more detailed dispersion chart $n(\lambda)$ you can check at [refractiveindex.info](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=other&book=air&page=Ciddor), superb optical properties database :-)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Thanks! I found my answer.